# Use placeholder as shape of pooling in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a neural network in tensorflow, I have a function called CNN_model that takes as input three placeholders:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, 13])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
```

and

```
pool_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [1])
```

I run the session with the values:

```
feed_dict={X: x, Y: y, MFCCS: x.shape[0]}
```

In the session I want to do a max-pooling layer with it's shape defined by the placeholder like this:

```
pool_window_size = [pool_shape, pool_shape]

pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
        inputs = conv,
        pool_size = pool_window_size,
        strides = pool_window_size,
        name = "pool"
)
```

But I'm getting the error:

*TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'*

Which I'm assuming is because at that point "pool_shape" is a tensor not just an integer, is there a way to get the value of whatever is in the tensor at that point?

Comment: If may I ask, why do you want to change size of pooling kernel ? Could you think of a way to achieve your task without doing it ?

Comment: I want to use dynamic pooling because I have variable sized input example so I want the pooling layer to produce a fixed size output based on the shape of the example. I have been using zero-padding to make all the examples the same shape but I am worried that is worse for accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with your current session `sess` and with relevant inputs needed for `pool_shape` in your `feed_dict` as

```
dimension = pool_shape.eval(sess, feed_dict = {inputs})[0]
pool_window_size = [dimension , dimension]
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
I assume this is currently your code:

```
pool_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [1])
pool_window_size = [pool_shape, pool_shape]

#...

for i in range(iterations):
    sess.run(Optimizer, feed_dict = {X:x, Y:y, pool_shape:value} 
    #value is the length/width you want to set for the pool_window_size
```

Instead, i think this might work.

```
pool_window_size = [pool_shape, pool_shape]

#...

for i in range(iterations):
    pool_shape = value
    sess.run(Optimizer, feed_dict = {X:x, Y:y}
```

I'm not too sure if the maxpooling layer will update the pool_size, you can try and tell me.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I'm still not having any luck getting the value out of the tensor during training. When I want to get the value I am already running a session with:

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I'm still not having any luck getting the value out of the tensor during training. When I want to get the value I am already running a session with: `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y, MFCCS: x.shape[1]})` The train_op then calls my function where I want to get the value that I passed as `x.shape[1]` which has the variable name `pool_shape` but trying to run another session to get it's value with `print(input_mfcc_count.eval(feed_dict = {input_mfcc_count: input_mfcc_count}))` it says I cannot pass a tensor "input_mfcc_count" to a feed_dict.

Comment: If assuming you wrote `print(input_mfcc_count.eval(feed_dict = {input_mfcc_count: input_mfcc_count}))` in your code, then that may be the issue with your understanding. In order to obtain the length/width of the `pool_window_size`, it determines its values from the variable `pool_shape`. You may have to observe if obtaining the `pool_window_size` depends on other values as well, by observing its connections to variables higher in the hierarchy, up till the placeholder input level. In this case, your `feed_dict` should just be `feed_dict= {pool_shape:value}` where `value` is the length/width

Comment: You could also use and assign global variables to the image size, if each training batch has the same image dimensions, instead of parsing them through the session.

Comment: Thanks @joshua but I'm still having trouble. I am already in a session when I am trying to get the value. I pass the session an integer (through a placeholder and feed_dict) each time it is run then I want to access that value as in integer in my function the session calls. So I don't know what to put for `value` in your example, my function receives only the tensor `input_mfcc_count` at which point I want to find it's value. Sorry if I'm not explaining this well, I'm new to TensorFlow.